# Relacionar html y php en un solo archivo

Tags: php, html, mysql

Soy bastante nuev en php, sin embargo, mi conexión con el servidor es exitosa, lo que me dificulta es hacer una tabla en HTML con los campos que extraen de la conexión y quiero que los resultados me muestren la tabla y algo que estoy haciendo mal porque en la parte de arriba me muestra los resultados de la conexión y abajo la tabla. Mi objetivo es que la tabla me muestre los resultados de cada campo conectado entre si! Aqui les muestro mi codigo

```
<?php
$servername = "xxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "";
$db = "xxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$mysqli = new mysqli("xxxxx", "xxxx", "", "xxxxx");

/* comprueba la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


/* devuelve el nombre de la base de datos actualmente seleccionada */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE(chat)")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}
/* cambia de test bd a world bd */
$mysqli->select_db("xxxx");
/* devuelve el nombre de la base de datos actualmente seleccionadae */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}
/*selecciona campos de la tabla*/
$sql = "SELECT date, threads, operator_msgs, user_msgs, missed_threads, avg_waiting_time, invitations_sent, invitations_accepted, invitations_rejected, invitations_ignored  FROM cgchat";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "date: " . $row["date"]. " threads: " . $row["threads"].  "Operator messages: " . $row["operator_msgs"]. " User messages: " . $row["user_msgs"]. "Missedthreads " . $row["missed_threads"]. "Average waiting time " . $row["avg_waiting_time"]. "Sentinvitations: " . $row["invitations_sent"]. " Acceptedinvitations: " . $row["invitations_accepted"].  "Rejectedinvitations: " . $row["invitations_rejected"]. " Ignoredinvitations: " . $row["invitations_ignored"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$mysqli->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


  <FORM action="conex.php" method="post">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>DataTables example - Multiple tables</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://www.datatables.net/rss.xml">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/site-examples.css?_=6e5593ad4c5375eef5d919cfc10a0a54">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <style type="text/css" class="init">

  div.dataTables_wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
  }

  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/site.js?_=88b8e26b7e3dd4eee69f199f9880a0e0">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/dynamic.php?comments-page=examples%2Fbasic_init%2Fmultiple_tables.html" async>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js"> 
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table.display').DataTable();
} );

  </script>
</head> 

<body class="wide comments example">

  <a name="top" id="top"></a>
  <div class="form-header">
                    <div class="form-header-inwards"></div>
                </div>


        <table id="" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Threads</th>
              <th>Operator messages</th>
              <th>User messages</th>
              <th>Missedthreads</th>
              <th>Average waiting time</th>
              <th>Sentinvitations</th>
                        <th>Acceptedinvitations</th>
              <th>Rejectedinvitations</th>
              <th>Ignoredinvitations</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

[image: Aqui pueden ver pantalla de ejecucion de mi codigo]

el resultado que aparece en la parte de arriba de la imagen 
quiero que me lo muestre pero en la tabla que se muestra, segun yo lo quiero hacer en un solo archivo ya que si serian dos solo requiero un poco de ayuda que me explicaran como lo haria.?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que pude apreciar realmente eres nuevo en php. La manera de renderizar datos traidos de una base de datos en una tabla debes unir las dos partes en un mismo fragmento de código, no por separado como lo que has hecho hasta el momento. Por ejemplo si quieres mostrar el nombre de un usuario que tienes en una variable dentro de un elemento span de html seria de esta manera:

```
$name = "Pedro";
//para mostrarlo en html
echo "<span>".$name."</span>";
// o tambien: echo "<span>{$name}</span>";
```

Entonces, entendiendo esto puedes hacer lo que deseas, sabiendo que en el ciclo que tienes en las últimas líneas de tu código php le falta escribir los elementos tr y td que le corresponde a la tabla que quieres dibujar en html y moverlo hacia la parte de tu html donde creas el tbody, en fin algo como lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$servername = "xxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "";
$db = "xxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$mysqli = new mysqli("xxxxx", "xxxx", "", "xxxxx");

/* comprueba la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* devuelve el nombre de la base de datos actualmente seleccionada */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE(chat)")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}
/* cambia de test bd a world bd */
$mysqli->select_db("xxxx");
/* devuelve el nombre de la base de datos actualmente seleccionadae */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}
/*selecciona campos de la tabla*/
$sql = "SELECT date, threads, operator_msgs, user_msgs, missed_threads, avg_waiting_time, invitations_sent, invitations_accepted, invitations_rejected, invitations_ignored  FROM cgchat";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


  <FORM action="conex.php" method="post">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>DataTables example - Multiple tables</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://www.datatables.net/rss.xml">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/site-examples.css?_=6e5593ad4c5375eef5d919cfc10a0a54">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <style type="text/css" class="init">

  div.dataTables_wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
  }

  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/site.js?_=88b8e26b7e3dd4eee69f199f9880a0e0">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/dynamic.php?comments-page=examples%2Fbasic_init%2Fmultiple_tables.html" async>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js"> 
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table.display').DataTable();
} );

  </script>
</head> 

<body class="wide comments example">

  <a name="top" id="top"></a>
  <div class="form-header">
                    <div class="form-header-inwards"></div>
                </div>


        <table id="" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Threads</th>
              <th>Operator messages</th>
              <th>User messages</th>
              <th>Missedthreads</th>
              <th>Average waiting time</th>
              <th>Sentinvitations</th>
                        <th>Acceptedinvitations</th>
              <th>Rejectedinvitations</th>
              <th>Ignoredinvitations</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
            <?php
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["date"]. "</td><td>" . $row["threads"].  "</td><td>" . $row["operator_msgs"]. "</td><td>" . $row["user_msgs"]. "</td><td>" . $row["missed_threads"]. "</td><td>" . $row["avg_waiting_time"]. "</td><td>" . $row["invitations_sent"]. "</td><td>" . $row["invitations_accepted"].  "</td><td>" . $row["invitations_rejected"]. "</td><td>" . $row["invitations_ignored"]. "</td></tr>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<tr><td>0 results</td></tr>";
            }

            $mysqli->close();
            ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias me fue de mucha ayuda.! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mezclar tu código PHP con contenido HTML tanto como quieras. Sólo tienes que saber abrir y cerrar bien los bloques de PHP.

He cambiado lo siguiente:

1. Puse arriba la parte inicial de HTML, siguiendo un orden lógico de cómo se mostraría la página
2. En esa primera parte construimos los primeros elementos de la tabla. Esto se puede aún mejorar... por ejemplo, si no se encuentran datos la tabla no tiene por qué mostrarse.
3. Cuando llegamos a la lectura de los posibles resultados, yo creo una variable `$strHTML` a la cual le voy concatenando las diferentes filas/columnas. Eso nos evitará estar abriendo y cerrando bloques de PHP/HTML mezclados que en lo particular me parecen horribles, además de producir un código ilegible.
4. El foot de la tabla lo he dejado tal cual, ya que tu código no hace referencia a esos totales que quieres mostrar y tampoco es el objetivo de tu pregunta.
5. Al final cerramos la tabla.

El resultado sería este:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <FORM action="conex.php" method="post">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>DataTables example - Multiple tables</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://www.datatables.net/rss.xml">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/site-examples.css?_=6e5593ad4c5375eef5d919cfc10a0a54">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <style type="text/css" class="init">

  div.dataTables_wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
  }

  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/site.js?_=88b8e26b7e3dd4eee69f199f9880a0e0">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/dynamic.php?comments-page=examples%2Fbasic_init%2Fmultiple_tables.html" async>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js"> 
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table.display').DataTable();
} );

  </script>
</head> 
<body class="wide comments example">

  <a name="top" id="top"></a>
  <div class="form-header">
                    <div class="form-header-inwards"></div>
                </div>


        <table id="" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Threads</th>
              <th>Operator messages</th>
              <th>User messages</th>
              <th>Missedthreads</th>
              <th>Average waiting time</th>
              <th>Sentinvitations</th>
              <th>Acceptedinvitations</th>
              <th>Rejectedinvitations</th>
              <th>Ignoredinvitations</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
<?php
/*Ahora necesitamos PHP, abrimos un bloque*/
$servername = "xxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "";
$db = "xxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$mysqli = new mysqli("xxxxx", "xxxx", "", "xxxxx");

/* comprueba la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


/* devuelve el nombre de la base de datos actualmente seleccionada */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE(chat)")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
//    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}
/* cambia de test bd a world bd */
$mysqli->select_db("xxxx");
/* devuelve el nombre de la base de datos actualmente seleccionadae */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
//    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}
/*selecciona campos de la tabla*/
$sql = "SELECT date, threads, operator_msgs, user_msgs, missed_threads, avg_waiting_time, invitations_sent, invitations_accepted, invitations_rejected, invitations_ignored  FROM cgchat";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$strHTML="";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        /*La variable concatenará los valores de la tabla*/
        $strHTML="<tr>";
            $strHTML.="<td>".$row["date"]."</td>". 
                      "<td>".$row["threads"]."</td>". 
                      "<td>".$row["operator_msgs"]."</td>".
                      "<td>". $row["user_msgs"]."</td>".
                      "<td>".$row["missed_threads"]. "</td>".
                      "<td>".$row["avg_waiting_time"]."</td>".
                      "<td>".$row["invitations_sent"]."</td>".
                      "<td>".$row["invitations_accepted"]."</td>".
                      "<td>".$row["invitations_rejected"]."</td>".
                      "<td>".$row["invitations_ignored"]."</td>";
        $strHTML="</tr>";
    }
} else {
    $strHTML= "0 results";
}
echo $strHTML;
$mysqli->close();  /*Aquí termina todo el código PHP y seguimos con HTML*/
?>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Comment: Listo.!
Muchas gracias, mi error es mas logico pero con su ayuda lo analice mejor

Comment: @Angie.Edu, si alguna de las respuestas ha ayudado a resolver el problema, por favor, cuando sea posible lee: ❯ **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.