# Cómo incluir una pagina PHP en una de HTML

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando crear una página web, para ello estraje información mediante un programa llamado Octoparse, luego esos datos los guarde en una base de datos (MySQL) y para finalizar saqué esa información mediante PHP en forma de tabla.

Ahora tengo una página HTML y quiero meter esas tablas dentro del HTML pero me da un problema que es el siguiente:

```
 connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }
 ?>
```

Para incluir el PHP pongo lo siguiente:

```
href="C:\xampp\htdocs\frogak\england\championship.php">ENGLAND</a></li>
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? ¿Es posible hacerlo?

Comment: creo que estas planteando mal el problema. Lo mas correcto seria tener una pagina php, que lea los datos de bbdd y te genere una salida de html, no que tengas un html e incluyas un archivo .php dentro de ella.

Comment: Lo que dices se puede hacer, pero tendrías que cambiar la configuración del servidor, para que *interprete páginas html como si fuesen páginas php*. Ten en cuenta que eso supondría un riesgo que podría ser muy elevado... te podrían inyectar código dañino en el servidor con una facilidad que ni te imaginas. Por eso, como dice @jakala, lo normal sería hacerlo al revés. Además, con las redirecciones, es posible crear URLs amigables en las que la extensión .php  del archivo no tendría por qué verse. Con esta técnica, puedes ejecutar `archivo.php` y en el navegador mostrar solamente `archivo`.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano te he mandado un mensaje desde la pagina web que indicas en tu perfil jejej

Comment: Recibí tu mensaje :) Pero mi página no es sobre programación... En tu caso sería mejor crear un archivo PHP. Dentro de él puedes usar código HTML. [Aquí hay un ejemplo explicando con detalle lo que digo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132831/29967). El archivo tendría extensión `.php` y dentro de él habría tanto código HTML como código PHP. Esa sería la primera parte. Luego si quieres crear una URL amigable, puedes crear redirecciones que hagan que por ejemplo esto: `C:\xampp\htdocs\frogak\england\championship.php` se muestre así: `C:\xampp\htdocs\frogak\england\championship`, sin la extensión

Comment: Imanol lo mejor sería implementar un patrón MVC, creando un archivo `index.php` que haría de **C**ontrolador, en el **M**odelo iría todo lo relativo a los datos  y la **V**ista sería una clase a la que enviarías cualquier cosa que deba salir por pantalla. No es tan complicado, sólo que ahora mismo no tendría tiempo para explicártelo. [Aquí hay un ejemplo muy sencillo](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/). Yo **no implementaría para este caso el uso de `iframe`** como te sugiere @IsmaelGutierrez. El `iframe` es para otros usos y hasta podemos decir que es algo obsoleto.

Answer (score 0):

Para incluir una página PHP en una página HTML debes utilizar la etiqueta **iframe**:

```
<iframe src="localhost/frogak/england/championship.php"></iframe>
```

Pero antes deberías solucionar tus problemas de conexión.

Comment: Hola @Ismael Gutierrez que quieres decir, en vez de href que ponga iframe? si pero nose cual es el error de conexion...

Comment: He votado contra esta respuesta. Primeramente porque no es una respuesta, podría ser más bien un comentario. Y segundo, porque la mejor solución al problema planteado no sería recurrir al uso de `iframe`. Es más, el `iframe` para mí es algo que si no es ya obsoleto, pronto lo será. En este caso concreto, el uso de `iframe` sería la peor solución desde el punto de vista de experiencia de usuario.

Comment: Hola @ImanolGarmendia, si lo que quieres es acceder a la web en PHP cargándola en una página, la etiqueta que tienes está bien, aunque el contenido del href sería [b]href="localhost/frogak/england/championship.php"[/b], pero si lo que quieres es incrustar ese contenido en la página en HTML, sí deberías usar iframe u object

Answer (score -1):

Si no estás usando el paradigma MVC, pienso que lo mejor, y casi esencial es que utilices la lógica Modelo-Vista-Controlador. A la larga te resultará bastante mucho más sencillo, ya que obtendrás un código más oganizado y ordenado, más funcional y "fácil" de mantener, junto con una resolución de errores más rápida y efectiva.
Aquí de un ejemplo básico de este diseño en php nativo: [MVC - PHP Nativo](https://victorroblesweb.es/2013/11/18/tutorial-mvc-en-php-nativo/)