# ¿Como mostrar u ocultar un <div> con php?

Tags: php, html, css, css3

Quisiera saber una forma de como mostrar u ocultar un div según la respuesta de la base de datos con php
Codigo HTML (Este es el DIV que quiero ocultar o mostrar)

```
<div id="nameDiv">
  <h6 class="text-center">
     <?php
       if ($user_name) {
          echo $user_name;
       }
      ?>
  </h6>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Codigo PHP (Este es el que quiero, según el IF, que muestre u oculte el Div anterior

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  $user_id_query = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user_id_query'";
  $result = $conexion->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows==1) {
    $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $user_rol = $value['role'];
    $user_name = $value['name'];
    if ($user_rol == 1) {

    } if ($user_rol == 2) {

    }
  }
} else {

}
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Por qué hay que incluir aquello que no debe mostrarse? Lo lógico sería, desde el código PHP, según el `if`, crear únicamente los elementos que deberían mostrarse.

Comment: ¿Como podria crear el Div desde un codigo PHP?, no entiendo muy bien.

Comment: En PHP puedes poner también etiquetas HTML como `div` u otras, sea abriendo bloques HTML completos dentro del PHP sea concatenando variables y haciendo `echo` de ellas.

Comment: [Mira un ejemplo aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132831/29967) donde se escribe código PHP y HTML en un archivo con extensión PHP. Es un ejemplo parecido al tuyo, donde se consulta a MySQL, se leen los datos y se crea una tabla con ellos. En tu caso sería nada más cambiar los `div` por la tabla.

Comment: Pues solo aplica la condicion y el codigo que lo imprima php si la condicion es valida, puede usar el html como un string para hacerle un echo, si la condicion pasa

Answer (score 0):

la forma más correcta de hacerlo sería via php, metiendo tu div dentro de el if, es decir, si es rol 1 mostrará x div y si es rol 2 mostrará otro div.

Otra forma es hacerlo vía Jquery, ocultando el elemento según sea la respuesta de php.

Por ejemplo

```
     <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  $user_id_query = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user_id_query'";
  $result = $conexion->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows==1) {
    $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $user_rol = $value['role'];
    $user_name = $value['name'];
    if ($user_rol == 1) {
    echo '<script>$("#nameDiv").hide();</script>';
    } elseif ($user_rol == 2) {
    echo '<script>$("#nameDiv").show();</script>';
    }
  }

} else {

}
?>
```

Si el usuario es rol 1, lo ocultara el div con el id “nameDiv” gracias a la función hide.
Si es rol 2 lo muestra con la función show.

Saludos.

Comment: Disculpa pero no me funciona la solución, aunque la copié tal cual la enseñaste

Comment: Acabo de realizar unos pequeños cambios, prueba de nuevo el codigo php.